# vim colorscheme not working in terminal vim but working in gvim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, color-scheme

I am using the vim solarized color scheme.
the following is the setting in my `.vimrc` file

```
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

the following image is the vim rendering between the terminal and the gvim[image]
What can i do to fix the terminal vim?

Comment: Have you read the ["important note for terminal users"](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users)?

Comment: do i need to put this line in .vimrc let g:solarized_termcolors=256?

Comment: but if i would put that in the .vimrc before i set the colorscheme, the vim still doesnot show anything in a color scheme

Comment: 6 years of solarized being an horrible hack and users not reading the manual.

Comment: What do `echo &term` and `echo &t_Co` say? Do you, in fact, have a 256-colour terminal?

Comment: @amandan, i don't think i have 256-color terminal. How do i install that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+solarized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.
In the .vimrc following lines needed to be added

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=16 
set t_Co=256 
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

additionaly you can add the [gnome solarised](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized) to your terminal